# Inline HTML background-image using PHP logic?

Tags: php, html, wordpress, logic, background-image

Is it possible to use my PHP logic used to display a WordPress post's featured image as the inline background image of a div? Here is my attempt:

```
                <div class="rounding-image" style="background-image: url(
                    <?php
                        if ( $thumbnail == true ) {
                            // If the post has a feature image, show it
                            if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
                                the_post_thumbnail( $thumbsize );
                            // Else if the post has a mime type that starts with "image/" then show the image directly.
                            } elseif ( 'image/' == substr( $post->post_mime_type, 0, 6 ) ) {
                                echo wp_get_attachment_image( $post->ID, $thumbsize );
                            }
                        }
                    ?>
                )"></div>
```

This isn't throwing a specific error, but rather displaying `)">` where the image would be.

Comment: I'm guessing **$thumbnail == false** here. You have no else in there to deal with this case. Try simply adding the else *where $thumbnail == false* and echo something out, anything at all. If this does echo out, you know what to do to deal with it.

Answer (score 1):

[the_post_thumbnail](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_post_thumbnail) displays the image with the `img` tag. What you want to do is get the image URL

```
$thumb = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'full' ); $url = $thumb['0'];

if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {echo $url;}
```

Answer (score 0):

I like to use background-size: cover if its full width.  if it's not just remove that part of the css

```
<?php if (has_post_thumbnail( $page->ID ) ) { ?>
      <?php $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $page->ID ), 'single-post-thumbnail' ); ?>

<header style="background:url(<?php echo $image[0]; ?>) 50%  50% no-repeat;background-size: cover;-webkit-background-size: cover;-moz-background-size: cover;-o-background-size: cover;background-size: cover;"></header>

<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this, it will set the background image to the featured image if one exists. This allows you to set a default via CSS in case a featured image is not set.

```
<?php 
    global $post; 
    $src = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), array( 5600,1000 ), false, '' ); 
    if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) :
?>

    <div class="rounding-image" style="background: url(<?php echo $src[0]; ?> ) !important;">
<?php else : ?>
    <div id="rounding-image">
```